# Is there any software available on Mac OS X that can remotely control my Canon G10?

Tags: canon, software, tethering, macintosh

I'd like software to remotely (via USB tether) control my G10 from my MacBook running OS X 10.6. This software seems to do exactly what I want, but for Windows:

http://www.breezesys.com/PSRemote/index.htm

Anything similar for the Mac?

I have a house finch nest on the side of my house and I have a webcam trained on it, getting some ok shots, but I really want to get high-quality stills of the little chicks and mom, it's pretty adorable. Thanks!

Apparently, the CameraWindow software from Canon will do this, but you can't download it and I have no idea where the CD that came with the camera is.

I've also tried Capture One Pro 6, but it doesn't recognize when the G10 is attached.

Answer (score 4):

[gPhoto](http://www.gphoto.org/) can be installed on a Mac (it may be [difficult](http://blog.dcclark.net/2009/05/how-to-gphoto-primer.html) a bit). It [supports](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php) Canon G10.

Comment: Thans asalamon! I'm giving it a shot... it's installed, but it doesn't seem to recognize my G10. Working on it.

Comment: So far, no luck. Says 'Could not claim the USB device', doesn't show any cameras as attached. I am able to use ImageCapture to take pictures, but there are no controls, so I can't zoom, focus, preview, etc.

Comment: Progress! Killing the PTP process helped... it now displays info about the camera. I have gotten as far as running --capture-inage, and it opens the lens, but seems to hang there.

Comment: Still haven't been able to take an actual picture, although it sees the camera and gets as far as opening the lens.

Answer (score 0):

You can download **ImageBrowser** for OSX from the Canon website, and use that to do tethered shooting with a G10.